# Unquoted vectors in R5RS Scheme

Tags: parsing, scheme

I'm trying to write a scheme parser as an exercise, but I'm not sure how to implement the vector syntax.  The [specification](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_sec_6.3.6) seems to indicate that the way to input a vector is `'#(1 2 3)` and such a vector should evaluate to `#(1 2 3)`.  However, when I experimented in several Scheme implementations, `#(1 2 3)` was accepted as valid input as well.  Is this a universally implemented extension to the spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the R<sup>5</sup>RS spec, vectors must be quoted:

> Note that this is the external representation of a vector, not an expression evaluating to a vector. Like list constants, vector constants must be quoted:
>
> ```
> '#(0 (2 2 2 2) "Anna")
> ```

Some implementations have chosen to allow evaluation of unquoted vectors, but any such extensions are non-standard, and a "feature" of that particular implementation.

---

For what it's worth, the upcoming [R<sup>7</sup>RS spec](http://trac.sacrideo.us/wg/raw-attachment/wiki/WikiStart/r7rs.pdf) explicitly requires vectors to self-evaluate:

> Vector constants are self-evaluating, so they do not need to be quoted in programs.

Answer (score 1):

Not universal at all. [Chicken](http://www.call-cc.org/), for example, will not allow you to evaluate an unquoted vector.

```
#;1> #(1 2 3)

Error: illegal non-atomic object: #(1 2 3)
#;1> '#(1 2 3)
#(1 2 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Funny things about standards and implementations. An implementation can give you lots of features as long as they don't collide with the spec. So one implementation wanted #(1 2 3) to be evaluated as if it was self evaluation and it's ok because that will never happen in a R5RS conforming program anyway. In R5RS, running a non R5RS conforming program like

```
(define test "hello")
(string-set! test 0 #\H)
```

Is undefined. It could fail, not change test silently or change test. Same goes for R6RS but an implementation might signal an error - but still don't have to.

AFAIK `racket` has the most strict R5RS, but even their implementation has som extras still. Eg. they allow symbols that are not allowed in the spec and [they have symbols defined in their report-environment](http://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs-mod.html#%28part._.Non-.R5.R.S_.Bindings_from_r5rs%29) to boostrap R5RS in racket's module system. However, like all implementations there are little errors when given a R5RS conforming program.